# Dumping all variables to a text file

Tags: powershell, debugging, memory-leaks

I've made a windows forms application that seems to create a memory leak very occasionally. Is there a way to dump all variable information to a text file so I can look through it and see what might be causing this?

Comment: create a dmp file of the process and analyze the dmp with DebugDiag analyzer

Comment: `Get-Variable |ConvertTo-Json |Out-File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Get-Variable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849899.aspx) lists all variables with their values. There are various ways of dumping this information into a file, e.g.:

```
Get-Variable | Export-Csv 'C:\variables.csv'
Get-Variable | Export-Clixml 'C:\variables.xml'
(Get-Variable | ConvertTo-Xml).Save('C:\variables.xml')
Get-Variable | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File 'C:\variables.json'
Get-Variable | Format-Table -Wrap | Out-String | Out-File 'C:\variables.txt'
...
```

Comment: ConvertTo-Json complains about an existing key, and ConvertTo-XML complains about a null value. Though Export-csv should work! Thank you.